# why in $ C^*$-algebra generated by $ x$ that denote by $ A[x]$, $ A[x]$ is commutative?

Tags: functional-analysis

suppose $ A$ is a $ C^*$-algebra and $ x$ is a normal element in $ A $. $ C^*$-algebra generated by $ x$ denote by $ A[x]$. then

1) $ A[x]$ is commutative.

2) $ A[x]$ is the clouser of polynomials of two variable $ x$ and $ x^*$.

in every book that I read, (1) and (2) is clear from author's point of view. But I dont understand why. 
Please help me about (1),(2)and say what is the form of elaments of $ A[x]$.
thanks

Comment: Please use a title that means something by itself.

Comment: $A[x]$ is bad notation, since this usually refers to the smallest algebra (inside a larger one, or the universal example) containing $A$ and $x$. But here $A[x]$ is contained in $A$. A better and more common notation would be $\mathbb{C}[x]$ or (in order to emphasize the $C^*$-structure) $C^*[x]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do this backwards :

Let $D$ denote the closure of all polynomials in $x$ and $x^{\ast}$. Since $xx^{\ast} = x^{\ast}x$, any two polynomials commute. Hence, $D$ is commutative.

Clearly, $D$ is a C* algebra and contains $x$. Any other C* algebra $B$ that contains $x$, must contain $x^{\ast}$, and hence must contain all polynomials in $x$ and $x^{\ast}$. Thus, $D\subset B$.

Hence, $D = A[x]$, and so (1) and (2) hold.